# Obtener fecha del cliente no la del "SERVIDOR" en C#

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc

Estoy intentando capturar la fecha de un cliente que se LOG IN en mi portal. al utilizar `DateTime.Now` estoy capturando la hora del servidor, lo que necesito es obtener la hora de mi cliente, ya que el servidor se encuentra en un país donde el horario no coincide con la fecha y hora de mi cliente.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Tienes una pregunta abierta. la cual no tiene una contestacion que hayas aceptado (o no sirvio, y deberias aclarar porque). Lo que pedis aca se hace usando JS para obtener datos del cliente y despues pasarlos al servidor. yo cambiaria las etiquetas de la pregunta para que alguien con conocimientos de JS pueda ayudarte

Comment: Javascript FTW... `var fechaCliente = new Date();`

Comment: Datos a considerar: 1. ¿Tu cliente pertenece a una zona horaria donde el tiempo varía en verano? 2. Se te hará más sencillo si trabajas todo en base la hora del servidor en UTC y luego en las reglas de negocio conviertes a hora local

Answer (score 3):

Obtener la fecha del cliente con un lenguaje del servidor? Imposible. Tendras que generarla con javascript en el cliente y enviarla al servidor.

Puedes utilizar un `input[hidden`] para guardar la fecha del cliente y el form enviarla:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#fecha_cliente");
var fechaCliente = new Date();
input.value = fechaCliente.getDay() + "/" + fechaCliente.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + fechaCliente.getFullYear();
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fecha_cliente" id="fecha_cliente"/>
```

Solo tendrias que cambiarle el tipo `text` a hidden y listo.

**Actualizacion:**

Aqui la forma de convertir la fecha a `System.DateTime` cuando la recibas en el servidor:

```
 var dateParts = fecha_cliente.Split('/').Select(Int.Parse).ToArray();
 var fechaCliente = new DateTime(day: dateParts[0], month: dateParts[1], year:dateParts[2]);
```

Comment: Claramente expreso que esta utilizando `DateTime.Now` para obtener la fecha del cliente y es la manera incorrecta de hacerlo. Por lo que especifique que debe de hacer. Aun asi actualize mi respuesta con un ejemplo para guiarlo un poco. Gracias por la observacion.

Comment: Ahora ya es una respuesta para mi :)

Comment: ahora es otra cosa +1

Comment: @Einer vi tu respuesta  y lo voy  a probar y te cuento como va.

Comment: @ManuKeteImporta te funciono la respuesta?